# How to distribute iOS older versions of Apps to only clients

Tags: ios, app-store, b2b

I've been in googling to find out my solution for our business model since last 3 days but i'm still not finalised, Let me explain we're selling solution our product which include server, web, mobile apps(iOS and Android), we're in process to release different versions of our product Some of our clients don't to want upgrade, lets say we released version 3.0, some clients upgraded but some don't want they want to stick to version 2.0, but on both mobile apps stores apps are updated to 3.0 and if someone deleted their old apps from their device then they only have option to app 3.0.

As you know we can dealt with Android apps as we can generate .apk file which can download to every device, so to dealt with above problem we send them older version of apps downloadable link (lets say we use diawi), so they can use android app 2.0 with server 2.0

But when we come to iOS we've three options

- Developer Account (Appstore or restricted to 100 devices)
- Enterprise Account (can go more than 100 devices but only for inhouse, not for clients)
- Apple Business Manager (B2B solution), it fit into our requirement but how to download older version of apps ? is there any versioning control on their platform as I've no idea about this.

Forgive me if I explained little much but I'm still looking for solution to which will fit into our requirement.

Looking for suggestion and help. 
Thanks

Comment: How are you distributing at this point?

Comment: As I explained for now I'm using Appstore, but i'm still looking for solution which will fit into our business model and also distribute older version of apps.

Comment: You could use the B2B solution and provide specific versions of the app to specific clients. Each version would effectively be a different app (different bundle id)

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you please refer some link where mention that version controlling ?

Comment: You're not listening to what Paulw11 is telling you. There is no "version controlling". You maintain _multiple apps_ which happen to be based, perhaps, on a common code base, and you distribute _different apps to different clients_.

Comment: Yes, what Matt said.

Comment: This is what currently we were doing but Apple rejected our apps because of Spam policy as Apple don't link same app with different bundle id https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/